# Hacer Login a una web externa desde CURL PHP

Tags: php, html, json, login, curl

Hola estoy intenando hacer login a una pagina mediante curl y php para obtener unas credenciales voip de un json mediante api pero dicha api tiene restriccion por inicio de sesion, al ejecutar el codigo esta solo me arroja el error de usuario no autorizado a continuacion el codigo

```
<?php 
    $url = 'https://www.textnow.com/login'; //URL en la que iniciare sesion
    $ch = curl_init();
    $parametros_post = 'username='.urlencode("MIUSUARIO").'&password='.urlencode("MICONTRASEÑA");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros_post);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $parametros_post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $parametros_post);

    //Guardar página
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //Comprobar si ha hecho login en la página
    echo $result;

  $JSONData = 
  file_get_contents("https://www.textnow.com/api/users/MI_USUARIO");
  $dataObject = json_decode($JSONData);
  echo "<b> Usuario: </b>", $dataObject->sip_username;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<b> Password: </b>", $dataObject->sip_password;
  ?>
```

Pero al ejecutarlo solo me arroja el error:

```
Oops!
Your call could not be completed as dialed.
This page no longer exists or the wrong URL was entered.

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.textnow.com/api/users/MI_USUARIO): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 29
Usuario: Notice: Trying to get property 'sip_username' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 31
Password: Notice: Trying to get property 'sip_password' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\index.php on line 33
```

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

Comment: La API no explica qué código debes escribir, cómo debes mandar las credenciales para autentificarte, el mensaje de error parece claro: *`failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`*  Puede que estés mandando mal las credenciales o usando mal la URL que esta acepta para procesar la petición.